# Can I use .obb file in my app even if it's below 50 mb?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android application that has a lot of images to use inside of it.
Great, now I want to secure these images so I tend to use .obb file and store these images in that file.
Now I'm wondering if I can do this operation or not ?
Should I have an app that's above 50 mb in order to user .obb file or what ever was the size ?
Can I secure my images in another way without using .obb file ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use OBB files even in smaller Apps. There isn't any limit.